# Insert a space character before and after a specific string, yet preserve string, in one update SQL statement (MS SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I require an update statement that will run and insert spaces before and after the string "effective from". So in the following data...

```
£140,000effective from01-NOV-18
£40,000effective from01-NOV-18
£12,000effective from01-NOV-19
```

This becomes ...

```
£140,000 effective from 01-NOV-18
£40,000 effective from 01-NOV-18
£12,000 effective from 01-NOV-19
```

But, it must first detect that the row value has not already been processed, i.e. only insert spaces when the string contains 1x space character

Best Regards

Comment: You could try `LIKE` to match rows where `effective from` is surrounded by digits.

Comment: And if there's space before, but not after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a regular replacement:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET data = REPLACE(data, 'effective from', ' effective from ')
WHERE data LIKE '%[0-9]effective from[0-9]%';
```

This replacement only targets `effective from` when it is sandwiched in between two numbers.